# Group by laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, count, group-by, eloquent

Please, I want to make this query to be eloquent but I don't know how to make it.

I want to use **count** with **Group By** and order by **count desc**

```
->groupBy('room_id')->get();
```

but I can not.

Here is my original query:

```
 SELECT * , count(seeker_id) FROM `jobs_skills` WHERE ( skill_id =2 OR skill_id =3 OR skill_id=5) group by seeker_id ORDER BY count(seeker_id) DESC
```

I spent a lot of time to solve it but I can't do it.

Please help me.

Comment: what did you've tried ? , it's unclear what you exactly want

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, have you got a relationship set up between `job_skills` and `seekers`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you add * in select make sure you include the extra fields in groupBy statement.

```
   $skills = JobsSkills::selectRaw('skill_id, count(seeker_id) as count')
                         ->where('skill_id', 2)
                         ->orWhere('skill_id', 3)
                         ->orWhere('skill_id', 5)
                         ->groupBy('seeker_id')
                         ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
                         ->get();
```